# Flux endpoint from infinite java stream

Tags: java, project-reactor, spring2.x

I have an issue while processing a flux that is built from a `Stream.generate` construct.

The Java stream is fetching some data from a remote source, hence I implemented a custom supplier that has the data fetching logic embedded, and then used it to populate the Stream.

```
Stream.generate(new SearchSupplier(...))
```

My idea is to detect an empty list and use the Java9 feature of `takeWhile` ->

```
Stream.generate(new SearchSupplier(this, queryBody))
            .takeWhile(either -> either.isRight() && either.get().nonEmpty())
```

(using Vavr's Either construct)

The repositoroy layer flux will then do:

```
return Flux.fromStream (
            this.searchStream(...) //this is where the stream gets generated
        )
        .map(Either::get)
        .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable);
```

The "service" layer is composed of some transformation steps on the flux, but the method signature is something like `Flux<JsonObject> search(...)`.

Finally, the controller layer has a GetMapping:

```
@GetMapping(produces = "application/stream+json")
public Flux search(...) {
    return searchService.search(...) //this is the Flux<JsonObject> parth
         .subscriberContext(...) //stuff I need available during processing
         .doOnComplete(() -> log.debug("DONE")); 
}
```

My problem is that the Flux seems to never terminate. 
Doing a call from Postman for example just shot the 'Loading...' part in the response section. When I terminate the process from my IDE the results are then flushed to postman and I see what I'm expecting. Also the doOnComplete lambda never gets called

What I noticed is that if I change the source of a Flux:

```
Flux.fromArray(...) //harcoded array of lists of jsons
```

the doOnComplete lambda is called and also the http connection closes, and results are displayed in postman.

Any idea of what might be the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I found a way of signaling the completion of the flux, by setting a timeout in the controller and calling onComplete on the subscriber:

.timeout(ofSeconds(10), Subscriber::onComplete)
            .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("DONE"));

Now the doOnComplete lambda is called and the http connection is closed

Comment: Why not directly create a Flux using `Flux.generate`? You can use `sink.complete` to signal completion and terminate the Flux when the condition is reached.

Comment: I'll try; was using the Stream.generate thing from an older implementation that I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the Flux directly using code that looks like this. Note that I'm adding some assumed methods which you would need to implement based on your how your SearchSupplier works:

```
Flux<SearchResultType> flux = Flux.generate(
            () -> new SearchSupplier(this, queryBody),
            (supplier, sink) -> {
                SearchResultType current = supplier.next();
                if (isNotLast(current)) {
                    sink.next(current);
                } else {
                    sink.complete();
                }
                return supplier;
            },
            supplier -> anyCleanupOperations(supplier)
        );
```

Comment: Yeah, the flux generate method did work. I tried it after seeing your comment. Still not sure why the takeWhile on the java stream doesn’t terminate though. Will accept the answer, thx

Comment: Unfortunately I can't explain why the stream doesn't terminate or propagate the termination to the Flux without seeing the details of your SearchSupplier implementation.

Comment: No worries, would have shared it if allowed.